# Replace "Algorithm" in algorithm package

Tags: languages, algorithms

I use the latex package `algorithm`. I would like the name of my algorithm ("Algorithm 1.1") to be change to the french version ("Algorithme 1.1") in the compiled pdf document. How could I do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following command line to load the algorithm package:

```
\usepackage[Algorithme]{algorithm}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why this might be a solution such that other users do not have to look into manuals?